# DB2 EXTERNAL STORED PROCEDURE(JAVA)

Tags: java, stored-procedures, db2, external, db2-luw

I been trying my luck to call a java jar file which has a method that takes String and boolean as input parameters.

The stored procedure is as below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TBF_STG.PROC( IN in1 VARCHAR(25), OUT out1 BOOLEAN )
  LANGUAGE java
  PARAMETER STYLE java 
  DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
  FENCED 
  EXTERNAL NAME 'name1:connection.Connect.javastp'
```

I call the procedure as below:

```
CALL TBF_STG.PROC('xyz', ?)
```

The java class is as below:

```
public class Connect {
    static Connection con = null;
    public static void javastp( String name,
            Boolean outparm, 
            ResultSet[] rs 
            )
                    throws SQLException
    {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:default:connection" );
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        String sql = "SELECT NAME FROM TBF_STG.TEST WHERE NAME = ?";

        //Prepare the query with the value of name  
        stmt = con.prepareStatement( sql );
        stmt.setString( 1, name );

        //Execute query and set output parm
        rs[0] = stmt.executeQuery();
        outparm = true;

        //Close open resources
        if (stmt != null) stmt.close();
        if (con != null) con.close();  

        return;
    }
}
```

When i change the boolean parameter to String it works fine but i cant seem to make it work for boolean parameter.

I get the following error in dbeaver:

```
SQL Error [42724]: Java stored procedure or user-defined function "TBF_STG.PROC", specific name "SQL200804144354782" could not call Java method "javastp", signature "(Ljava/lang/String".. SQLCODE=-4306, SQLSTATE=42724, DRIVER=4.8.86
```

Can somebody please point me in the right direction as am new to DB2.

Comment: Which platform of Db2-SERVER ( is the database on Z/OS, or i-series, or Linux/Unix/Windows) ?  What is the Db2-server version?

Comment: Linux Suse
db2 version 11

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious how it could work at all with a String parameter in the way you provided.
[Parameter style JAVA procedures](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/c0023926.html):

> **SQL-arguments**
> Corresponds to the list of input parameters in the CREATE PROCEDURE statement. **OUT or INOUT mode parameters are passed as
> single-element arrays**. For each result set that is specified in the
> DYNAMIC RESULT SETS clause of the CREATE PROCEDURE statement, a
> single-element array of type ResultSet is appended to the parameter
> list.

[Supported SQL data types in Java routines](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/r0006275.html):

```
| SQL Column Type | Java Data Type |
+-----------------+----------------+
| BOOLEAN         | boolean        |
```

You must use `boolean` primitive type, not `java.lang.Boolean` class.
So, try:

```
public static void javastp( String name,
        boolean[] outparm, 
        ResultSet[] rs 
        )
....
    //Execute query and set output parm
    rs[0] = stmt.executeQuery();
    outparm[0] = true;
```

Comment: but for boolean[] i get the following error
SQL Error [38501]: Procedure or user-defined function "TBF_STG.PROC2", specific name "SQL200805103049789" aborted with an exception "java.lang.NullPointerException".. SQLCODE=-4302, SQLSTATE=38501, DRIVER=4.8.86

Comment: Look into the db2diag.log on the server to determine the line of your code throwing this exception.

Comment: for string i used the --String[]-- array ie., public static void javastp( int inparm, String[] outparm, ResultSet[] rs ) and that works fine but i cant get the boolean[] to work

Answer (score 0):

Db2-LUW versions 11.x have a software defect for java sprocs that set OUTPUT parameters of type `boolean` ( the sproc will throw NullPointerException when setting a boolean output parameter in the java code).

The first fix will appear in V11.1.m4FP6. The expectation is that when you apply that fixpack then your java procedures will be able to successfully set boolean output parameters without causing exceptions.

The defect number is IT35542

As per https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/IT35542